# How to remove image boundary while using LaTeX in wordpress

Tags: math-mode, framed

I'm using LaTeX in my blog in wordpress but the formulas are coming inside a rectangular box.

Please refer [here.](http://neerajbhauryal.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/talk-at-iiser-mohali/)

How can I remove them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Seems like this is off-topic here since it is more a matter of the Wordpress software.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with LaTeX. It's your CSS that contains a rule to apply a box-shadow to all `img` elements.
You can remove that by setting

```
img.latex { box-shadow: none; }
```

Comment: what is CSS? And where do I remove the settings?